# Resubmit app when adding new non-consumable product

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

Good day.

I've added an In-App Purchase non-consumable product to my existing app for the first time (just to test), and iTunes Connect displayed a message:

> Your first In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app
>   version. Select them from the In-App Purchases section of the Version
>   Details page and then click Ready to Upload Binary.

That's clear.

The question is: should I resubmit my app every time I add a new non-consumable product? So not just the first one, but every one?

Please answer if you've dealt with such case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This basically depends on your implementation of In-App-Purchases. If you hardcode your product identifiers you have to resubmit your app because your app doesn't know about the new product ids.

If you download the available product ids from your own web-server when you need them there is no need to submit a new app every time you add a new product.

Comment: Thank you. The question was asked to determine if app submission is required by iTunes Connect. Seems like it is not.